# Remote execution / debugging of Java code from Eclipse (or IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to test my code on remote boxes.

What I'd like to do:

- Edit my code in Eclipse locally.
- Set up a run configuration that points at a remote host (with login
  credentials).
- Click "run" and have it just work.

The IDE would connect via SSH, copy over or synchronize all of the files in the project to the remote box, run the java command remotely, and let me step through the code in my local IDE.

Possible?

I use Eclipse, but I'd pay for Intellij IDEA if it would do this one thing.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ Idea has remote debugging feature.

There is a "[remote](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-remote.html)" debug configuration option available

> Run > Debug > Edit Configuration > Add New > Remote

. You have to provide server configuration and connection parameters.

Both the Community Edition and Ultimate Editions have this feature.

I hope this is the feature you are looking.

Comment: Thanks. Does this copy over the project? I don't see that in the docs. It looks like you'd have to do that manually, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: You mean, once created, irrespective of project, the config should be available?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I mean that the project, and all the class files, should get copied or sync'd to the remote server. That's the only way to execute it on that server.